# Javascript Image After Loader

Tags: javascript, image, for-loop, onload

So I'm writing a javascript that replaces a default image that fills up the space for numerous images on my webpage. That way, the page loads much faster. (script is lauched with a body onload) all the default images have the same class and their id equals their filename.

```
function imgPostLoad(totalpics, placeholder) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < totalpics; i++) {
        var picture = document.getElementsByClassName(placeholder)[i];
        img.onload = function (evt) {
            picture.src = this.src;
            picture.width = this.width;
            picture.height = this.height;
        }
        img.src = "/img/" + picture.getAttribute("id") + ".jpg";
    }
}
```

It works but only for the very last last image in the array. The rest of the images just stay the same. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Think you need to put the `var img = ..` inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just simply do :

```
function imgPostLoad(totalpics, placeholder) {
    for (var i = 0; i < totalpics; i++) {
        var picture = document.getElementsByClassName(placeholder)[i];
        picture.src = "/img/" + picture.getAttribute("id") + ".jpg";
    }
}
```

What the problem is in your code is that by the time `img` was loaded `picture` is another variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
function imgPostLoad(placeholder) {
    var allPictures = document.getElementsByClassName(placeholder);
    for (var i = 0; i < allPictures.length; i++) {
        var picture = allPictures[i];
        picture.src = "/img/" + picture.getAttribute("id") + ".jpg";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it would be cleaner to write it like this.

```
function imgPostLoad() {

     var placeHolders = document.body.querySelectorAll('.placeholder');

    for (var i = 0; i < placeHolders.length; i++) {

        placeHolders[i].src = "/img/" + placeHolders[i].getAttribute("id") + ".jpg";
    }
}
```